# Commenting and Sharing with blog 7.6.1

Tags: typo3, blogs, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I try to setup the blog extension "blog" on a TYPO3 7.6.26 Installation. I tried the manual setup of the blog on an existing TYPO3 Installation and also used the SetupWizard on a clean TYPO3 7.6.26 Installation. In both cases I have the same problem: the comment form is not shown, although comments are active globally (I confirmed this in the TypoScript Object Browser) and on each post in the page properties Comments enabled is checked.
But the form is not shown. I looked into the templates and recognized that "post" is not set in Templates/Comment/Form.html - if I add content before the `<f:if condition="{post}">` this content is shown - content after the condition is not shown.
If I manually add a comment in the backend, in the Blog list the number of comments says: 1 comment. If I'm on this particular post, no comment is shown.

Also the sharing is not shown in the frontend although it is enabled. Any idea what's going wrong?
I set up a clean TYPO3 Installation with the blog template at http://www.t3test.toco3.com/ where you can see this happening...

Thank you for any hints!

Christian

Comment: I don't have enough information so I only can guess or give you some hints where to look. I would suspect two parts: 1. the caching or the missing deletion of cached content after adding a comment. 2. you have some errors in your fluid template. are the tags clean?

Comment: Thank you @BerndWilkeπφ - 1. Caching: I deleted all caches several times. 2. In my test installation the original fluid templates which are shipped with the extensions (blog and blog_template) are used (no customizations) - I also tried to drop blog_template and have the same issues. Are there any more information I can provide?

Comment: I manually added the plugins for comment form and comment list on this page with the same effect: http://www.t3test.toco3.com/index.php?id=7 - I added one comment in the backend to this post, which is displayed on the lists page: http://www.t3test.toco3.com/ (here you can see "1 comment")

Comment: at the moment external comments are stored twice, so my single comment was added twice. a typical problem if a plugin is include too often.

Comment: Thank you - Problem solved :-) 
plugin.tx_blog.persistence.storagePid  was set to a wrong pid!